# find the distribution of $Z = Y\sqrt X$

Tags: probability

A question in addition to: [Cauchy and $\chi^{2}$ dist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100795/cauchy-and-chi2-dist)

I have to find the distribution of $Z = Y\sqrt X$

I know Y is given by a fraction of 2 standard normal random variables ($Y = \frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}$) and $\sqrt X = V_{2}$ is a standard normal random variable and therefore I conclude that $Z = \frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}\cdot V_{2} = V_{1}$ is standard normal distributed.

Is this correct??

Comment: Is it truly $V_1/V_2$ and $V_2$?  If so then yes.

Comment: My question is related to the fact that I use that Y is cauchy distributed (i.e it is a fraction between two standard normal distributed variables) and $X$ is $\chi$ distributed (i.e it's the square of a standard normal distributed variable) to reduce that $Z=Y\sqrt X$ is standard normal distributed.

Comment: If $Y = \frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}$ and $X = V_{3}^2$, with the $V_i$ iid standard normals then $Y\sqrt X$ is not normally distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt X$ cannot be a standard normal random variable, since square-roots by convention non-negative.  So the question is flawed.

There is also a minor issue if $V_2=0$, but this has zero probability.

If $X= V_{2}^2$, and if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are *independent* standard normal random variables then  $\sqrt X = |V_2|$ and  $Z = Y\sqrt X = \text{sign}(V_2) V_1$, which indeed has a standard normal distribution.

Indeed you only need the *signs* of $V_1$ and $V_2$ to be independent, $V_1$ to be symmetrically distributed about $0$, and $V_2$ to have zero probability of being $0$,  for $Z$ and $V_1$ to have the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I see what my problem is. How do you conclude that $Z = sign(V_{2}) V_{1}$ has a standard normal distribution?

Comment: @user11775: because $\Pr(Z \le k) = \Pr(V_2 \gt 0)\Pr(V_1 \le k) +\Pr(V_2 \lt 0)\Pr(V_1\ge -k) $ $= (\Pr(V_2 \gt 0) + \Pr(V_2 \lt 0))\Pr(V_1\le k) = \Pr(V_1\le k)$

Comment: Smart! :) Thank you again.